# How to remap 'Esc' with '~'

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I have a laptop. The Esc key stopped working. I would like to swap it with ~ this key which is never used by me. I'm a complete beginner on linux. If anyone could help or point me in the direction of help it'd be great. Thanks

Comment: What version of Ubuntu, what desktop? Edit the information into your question, don't comment.